# SQL update column with data from another table's column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables:

1. Developers
2. Applications
3. ApplicationDevelopers (Join table)

I have a common attribute/**column** in the two tables (Developers, and Applications) which is called **filter_settings**.

I want to do a single SQL command to **update** the filter_settings in the Applications table from the **matching filter_seetings** column in the Developers table using the **join table**.

Here is what I am tried to not make the questions (do my homework kind on questions):

```
'UPDATE applications a INNER JOIN application_developers ad ON a.id = ad.application_id INNER JOIN developers d ON d.id = ad.id'
```

Comment: What does your update statement look so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How do these two tables relate to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this

```
Update Applications as app inner join Developers as dev on app.key_column=dev.key_column
set app.filter_settings=dev.filter_settings
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to update all records of a table. There is no need for a join here.

```
UPDATE applications
SET filter_settings = (<some query to get the value>);
```

But: There is a bridge table between Applications and Developers. It exists to implement an n:m relation between the two. Hence: Which Developers.filter_settings do you want to copy to an Applications record? Make this decision and then write the appropriate query.

Here is an example, simply taking the maximum filter_settings:

```
update applications a
set filter_settings = 
(
  select max(d.filter_settings)
  from developers d
  join applicationdevelopers ad on ad.developer_id = d.id
  where ad.application_id = a.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

update applications,developers set applications.filter_settings=developers.filter_settings where applications.primaryKey=developers.foreignKey